# Rails tutorial "No method error"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'am newbie in Rails. I'am currently working with ruby.railstutorial.org online tutorial. I've stucked on chapter 5. When I am trying to run sample app on my machine the following error is returned:

```
NoMethodError in Static_pages#home

Showing C:/rails_project/next_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `full_title' for #<#<Class:0x32de058>:0x32e47a8>

Extracted source (around line #4):

1: <!DOCTYPE html>
2: <html>
3:   <head>
4:     <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
5:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
6:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

Rails.root: C:/rails_project/next_app
```

Little explanation: I've changed name from 'Sample_app' to 'Next_app'

Thanks for help!

Ps. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have missed defining the helper method `full_title`

See this

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#code:title_helper

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are doing the 'railstutorials.org' sample tutorial. By memory, you have to make sure the full_title method is defined in the helpers. Try defining it in the Application Helper.